# problem in open cv, PILLOW, reading captcha image using open cv or PILLOW

Tags: opencv, python-imaging-library

When I am reading a captcha image using OpenCV, every pixel value becomes zero.
But when reading using PIL and displaying it, image is displayed as it is, but when I am converting it to array, pixel values  becomes zero.
I am attaching one sample image.

[image]

I tried with OpenCV, and Pillow.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the problem you occouring, may some line of code will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I split your image into its 4 constituent RGBA channels, R on the left through to A on the right with a magenta background and a 10px gap between the channels:

[image]

You can see that the RGB channels are empty (i.e. zero) and all the information is contained within the Alpha channel on the right.

By default, **OpenCV** will always give you a 3 channel RGB888 image unless you specify `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` on the `imread()`. So you need:

```
im = cv2.imread('PTbD6.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)[...,3]
```

which will read your image as 4-channel RGBA, then extract just the A channel.

---

Note that where the A channel is white (i.e. transparent), the black background shows through, so you will essentially get the inverse (photographic negative) of what you want. You can swap black and white like this:

```
im = ~im
```